# Parsing logs with fluentd

Tags: linux

I have this fluentd setup :

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  fluentd:
    image: fluentd:latest
    volumes:
      - ./fluentd.conf:/fluentd/etc/fluent.conf
    ports:
    - 24224:24224
```

fluentd.conf

```
<source>
  @type forward
  port 24224
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match docker.**>
  @type stdout
</match>

<filter docker.**>
    @type parser
    key_name log
    <parse>
        @type regexp
        expression /^(?<host>[^ ]*) .*$/
    </parse>
</filter>
```

And I run this apache container to test fluentd :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  httpd:
    image: httpd:latest
    logging:
      driver: fluentd
      options:
        tag: docker.httpd.log
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

When I make a `curl localhost`, I get this log in the fluentd tab :

```
fluentd_1  | 2019-06-18 13:31:20.000000000 +0000 docker.httpd.log: {"container_name":"/fluentd_httpd_1","source":"stdout","log":"172.22.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2019:13:31:20 +0000] \"GET / HTTP/1.1\" 200 45","container_id":"07dce5f130befb3a94bb193e76a1331844c08d5370f44fdcec81399a7e8ee7e3"}
```

I'm trying to figure out through this apache example how to use the regexp parse filter but I can't manage to get any part of the message in an independent field like `host: 172.22.0.1`

Do you know what i did wrong ?